# Setting input width with calc does not work as expected

Tags: html, css, css-position, css-calc

I have an input with `width: calc(100% - 100px);` without padding/margin/border. I want to put a div beside it with `position : inline-block;` and `width : 100px;`.

The div goes to the next line but I cannot find any reason for it. If I reduce the div width to 96px then it works fine. I am wondering what is causing that 4px missing width!

Please note that `box-sizing : borderbox` is not related to this issue as I do not have any padding or border.

Here is [the plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Fl8JLtTx3D1NpfrOJfXF?p=preview), tested with chrome and firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the white space between the elements. By default, inline and inline-block will preserve the space between elements since they're inline (just like spaces between words/letters). You can also put an HTML comment between them so there isn't a white space there.

```
<input type="test" style="width: calc(100% - 100px); padding: 0; border: 0; margin: 0; box-sizing:borderbox" value="100%-100px input"><div style="width: 97px; display: inline-block">97 px Div</div>
```

or

```
<input type="test" style="width: calc(100% - 100px); padding: 0; border: 0; margin: 0; box-sizing:borderbox" value="100%-100px input"><!--
--><div style="width: 97px; display: inline-block">97 px Div</div>
```

Comment: Thank you :) is there any way to disable this behavior? for example by adding something to DOCTYPE or html tag or meta?

Comment: @Arashsoft not that I'm aware. It's a fundamental aspect of html and css if you're using `inline` or `inline-block` elements. Just like letters/words, you want the space between them. inline elements are like letters/words.